# Consume Events from Azure EventHub using the sequence number in python

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-eventhub

I Have published several files into the event hub,
And for another purpose I want to download a specific file from the event  hub.
I have the file name with me and as well as the sequence number.

I used this method,

```
await client.receive(on_event=on_event,  starting_position="12856854")
```

And this is downloading all the files from position **12856854**.

But I want to download only one specific file.

As an example, I have published *sample_data.xml* and it's sequence number is *567890*

What I need here is I want to download *sample_data.xml* file from event hub.

Answer (score 0):

From the code line you've mentioned, starting_position will give us the beginning of partition. So that it will start from that particular point, it is mentioned as below:

```
await client.receive(
on_event=on_event,
starting_position="-1", 
)
```

Below script in this section reads the captured data files from your Azure storage account and generates CSV files for you to easily open and view.

```
import os
import string
import json
import uuid
import avro.schema

from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient, BlobClient
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter


def processBlob2(filename):
    reader = DataFileReader(open(filename, 'rb'), DatumReader())
    dict = {}
    for reading in reader:
        parsed_json = json.loads(reading["Body"])
        if not 'id' in parsed_json:
            return
        if not parsed_json['id'] in dict:
            list = []
            dict[parsed_json['id']] = list
        else:
            list = dict[parsed_json['id']]
            list.append(parsed_json)
    reader.close()
    for device in dict.keys():
        filename = os.getcwd() + '\\' + str(device) + '.csv'
        deviceFile = open(filename, "a")
        for r in dict[device]:
            deviceFile.write(", ".join([str(r[x]) for x in r.keys()])+'\n')

def startProcessing():
    print('Processor started using path: ' + os.getcwd())
    # Create a blob container client.
    container = ContainerClient.from_connection_string("AZURE STORAGE CONNECTION STRING", container_name="BLOB CONTAINER NAME")
    blob_list = container.list_blobs() # List all the blobs in the container.
    for blob in blob_list:
        # Content_length == 508 is an empty file, so process only content_length > 508 (skip empty files).        
        if blob.size > 508:
            print('Downloaded a non empty blob: ' + blob.name)
            # Create a blob client for the blob.
            blob_client = ContainerClient.get_blob_client(container, blob=blob.name)
            # Construct a file name based on the blob name.
            cleanName = str.replace(blob.name, '/', '_')
            cleanName = os.getcwd() + '\\' + cleanName 
            with open(cleanName, "wb+") as my_file: # Open the file to write. Create it if it doesn't exist. 
                my_file.write(blob_client.download_blob().readall()) # Write blob contents into the file.
            processBlob2(cleanName) # Convert the file into a CSV file.
            os.remove(cleanName) # Remove the original downloaded file.
            # Delete the blob from the container after it's read.
            container.delete_blob(blob.name)

startProcessing()
```

Refer [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-python#create-a-python-script-to-read-your-capture-files) for the process and more information.